# what are the ways to retrieve Power measurements of a Dell cluster (lot of questions)

Tags: dell, snmp, dell-poweredge, electrical-power

I have to get power measurements of a dell cluster (Linux OS) running a specific workload  , with an interval of 1 second (retrieveing power values every second) . I can either use Windows or Linux as a local machine to gather/collect the data.  The questions I have are

- **Is it possible to retrieve values every second ? Does the cluster return power values at that rate ?**
- If Dell OpenManage has to be installed on the cluster to return the power values to me, how can I know if it is installed ?
- Can I do it without Dell Open Manage being installed on the cluster ?
- I have installed Cacti on my local machine running fedora (with yum install cacti) .
  **Now how do I open the tool ?** (sorry for being so naive , I'm new to this and have no guidance from anyone)
- **I think I figured out the OID for getting power values from dell snmp manual . What command should I be using to retrieve the power measuerements now ?**

I'd be very thankful to anyone who resolves my questions as this is very important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of OMSA you have installed you may be able to see the power readings from the DRAC. I have some severs with iDrac 6 Enterprise and you can find this information under Power Monitoring.  A small section of whats there and what you can expect.  There are also physical units you can put between your server and power.

(sorry about the formatting)

Power Consumption
    Statistic   Last Minute     Last Hour   Last Day    Last Week
    Average Power Consumption   339W | 1157 BTU/hr  339W | 1157 BTU/hr  341W | 1164 BTU/hr  341W | 1164 BTU/hr
    Max Power Consumption   342W | 1167 BTU/hr  362W | 1236 BTU/hr  392W | 1338 BTU/hr  392W | 1338 BTU/hr
    Max Power Time  Thu Mar 03 2011 08:56:55 AM     Thu Mar 03 2011 08:25:24 AM     Thu Mar 03 2011 02:32:34 AM     Thu Feb 24 2011 03:04:28 PM
    Min Power Consumption   338W | 1154 BTU/hr  338W | 1154 BTU/hr  338W | 1154 BTU/hr  338W | 1154 BTU/hr
    Min Power Time  Thu Mar 03 2011 08:56:43 AM     Thu Mar 03 2011 08:08:14 AM     Wed Mar 02 2011 09:08:18 AM     Thu Feb 24 2011 09:08:12 AM